# php form showing php file and not sending it on

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using a php mailer script. when I hit submit on my forms. Instead of sending the email it just shows the php files script in my browser window:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" style="margin-top: 60px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name..." name="emailName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="You@example.com..." name="emailFrom">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Telephone Number..." name="emailTel">

    <button class="body">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
        var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
        for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) 
            eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="MM_goToURL('parent','<?php echo $_POST["emailSource"] ?>?sent=y');return document.MM_returnValue">
<?php
    require 'c:\php\includes\PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '***********';        // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = ***********;      // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '***********';    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '***********';    // SMTP password
                                        // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->From = '***********';
    $mail->FromName = '***********';
    $mail->addAddress($_POST["emailTo"]); // Name is optional
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                  // Set email format to HTML

    if (isset($_FILES['docload']) && $_FILES['docload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['docload']['tmp_name'],
                             $_FILES['docload']['name']);
    }

    $mail->Subject = $_POST["emailSubject"];
    $mail->Body    = 'Name: ' . $_POST["emailName"] . '<br>Email: ' . $_POST["emailFrom"] . '<br>Tel: ' . $_POST["emailTel"];

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo '';
?>
```

I have placed stars in where my details would normally be showing. I am not entirely sure what the error is here.

Comment: What's the extension of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds stupid, but did you make sure that the file ends with .php?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line

```
$mail->Body="Name: ".$_POST['emailName']."<br>Email: ".$_POST['emailFrom']."<br>Tel: ". $_POST['emailTel'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the PHP Files in your browser, then either PHP is not correctly installed on your server.